# FreeBSD install ejabberd from source missing yaml.h

Tags: installation, ejabberd, freebsd

I understand that in order to develop ejabberd module I must be able to compile it from the source.

I have FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p9, as a guest OS on a VirtualBox. So the followings are my attempts.

Using git, I clone the source to /usr/local/ejabberd as:

I run the following commands:

git clone git://github.com/processone/ejabberd.git ejabberd
cd ejabberd
./autogen.sh

./configure --enable-user=ejabberd --enable-mysql

gmake install

But I have the following error:

Compiling /usr/local/ejabberd/deps/fast_yaml/c_src/fast_yaml.c
/usr/local/ejabberd/deps/fast_yaml/c_src/fast_yaml.c:18:10: fatal error: 'yaml.h' file not found

ERROR: compile failed while processing /usr/local/ejabberd/deps/fast_yaml/:rebar_abort

Fyi, I have installed libyaml-0.1.7 using ports - I guess successully?

Any tips/advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at what FreeBSD [port does](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/net-im/ejabberd/Makefile?view=markup): it passes `-I/usr/local/include` into `CFLAGS` when running `make`. There are also a [bunch of patches](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/net-im/ejabberd/files/) for ejabberd, that are applied before compilation.

If you want to compile development version from source, you can try first running `make -C /usr/ports/net-im/ejabberd extract` and then putting sources from git into `/usr/ports/net-im/ejabberd/work` directory. Then running `make -C /usr/ports/net-im/ejabberd install` should install development package.

Comment: Thank you arrowd.

Comment: Thank you arrowd! I am a FreeBSD and *nix newbie. 

Anyway I think I can appreciate the -I/usr/local/include because I can see the "yaml.h" file is in the directory.

So I add a line CFLAGS+=-I/usr/local/include in the /ejabberd/Makefile file. (I followed the FreeBSD port's Makefile)

Then I ran make and gmake. 

It does not work.

Comment: I also followed your tips running make -C /usr/ports/net-im/ejabberd extract and putting sources from git. Then run make -C /usr/ports/net-im/ejabberd install.

But I got compilation failed unexpectedly..try to set MAKE_JOBS_UNSAFE=yes

I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Compiling development versions from source is no easy task. Look at errors you get, try to fix them. That MAKE_JOBS_UNSAFE isn't an actual error message, scroll up to see it.